# How can I use .all for last 2 days in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `submission` and currently I am displaying all the records in the database in the index page. In the `submissions` controller I have :

```
@submissions = Submission.all
```

However, now I only want the record for the past **two** days or the `name` field equals to some string, I tried this but it still shows all the records for me:

```
@submissions = Submission.all(:conditions => ["updated_at >= ? OR name = ?", 2.days.ago.to_date, "me"])
```

where `updated_at` and `name` are two fields in the `submissions` table.

Any idea where is wrong?

EDIT:

In my `submission` model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :updated_at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Arel (Rails 3), your conditions should be in a where method, with (optionally) at the end, like so

```
Submission.where("updated_at >= ? OR name = ?", 2.days.ago.to_date, "me").all
```

Comment: That`s not a problem. Your solution is Rails 3 syntax which is same as his. If this works that should also work. But still I recommend him to use your way.

Comment: @codeit, the mothod I am using in the question doesn't work for some reason, but this one works. Thanks for the answer and comment!